# How to count pages of a pdf file... ASP classic

Tags: pdf, asp-classic

I upload a PDF file to my web server.
I would like to be able to count the number of pages of the uploaded PDF file...
I'm new to the old asp classic (vb) so maybe someone can point me i a good direction or even give me a simple solution.

I just need to read the page count and i want to write this value to the webpage so it has to go into a variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Your best bet is a ASP COM Component like [Persits ASPPdf](http://www.asppdf.com/) which has this functionality built in, you might be able to work it out by reading the raw file but that will be a lot more work. Using something like ASPPdf it becomes as simple as `page_count = doc.Page.Count()`.

Comment: checking it out now... i'll get back

Comment: Thank you, but i trying to manage it by calling a *.exe that doest the job by writing the number of pages to a txt file...
Which is fine for me, but i'm having an issue there to, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645616/arguments-with-spaces