# Arguments with spaces

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I would like to pass some arguments to a little program i wrote.
Its a program that expects 2 arguments.
When i call it like this:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe d:\test\folder\ test.pdf
```

It works fine.

But when i try this:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe d:\test 2\folder\ test.pdf
```

It thinks is gets 3 arguments...

I tried quotes like this:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe "d:\test 2\folder\" test.pdf
```

No luck.

This is the vb code:

```
Module Module1
        Sub Main(ByVal sArgs() As String)
            If sArgs.Length = 0 Then
                ... some code
            ElseIf sArgs.Length = 2 Then
                ... some code
            End If
         End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: do you really have a file named " test.pdf"? At least explorer wont allow filenames with a leading or trailing space

Comment: @Plutonix: No, there is a space in the `test 2` folder name. The file name is a separate parameter, the space before it is the separator between the parameters.

Comment: sorry, misread.  where are you getting this problem.  In the IDE or runtime? quotes work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that when i use quotes arround first argument, i was actually escaping the closing qoute:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe "d:\test 2\folder\" test.pdf
```

This works fine now:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe "d:\test 2\folder" test.pdf
```

In combination with putting the \ inside the code of the program

Answer (score 5):

Command Line Arguments are Space Delimited.

If you need to pass an argument such as a filename that has (or may have) spaces you can enclose it in double quotes.

The exception to this is when arguments end with `\` in which case you have to escape this with another `\`

So in your case this is what you need:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe "d:\test 2\folder\\" "test.pdf"
```

So your code would look like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
    Debug.Writeline(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(i))
Next
```

Output:

```
d:\test 2\folder\
test.pdf
```

A simpler approach might be to remove the trailing slash and add the directory and filename together using `Path.Combine` or just pass the fully qualified name as the argument (enclosed in double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The argument parsing har some strange rules for escaping characters, it's the `\"` character combination in the arguments that causes the problem. This is a problem with the `CommandLineToArgvW` method in Windows. See for example the article [Commandline args ending in \" are subject to CommandLineToArgvW whackiness](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/10/05/_5B002E00_NET-Gotcha_5D00_-Commandline-args-ending-in-_5C002200_-are-subject-to-CommandLineToArgvW-whackiness.aspx)

Get the unparsed command line and parse it to get the parameters as expected:

```
Dim arguments As String() = _
  Regex.Matches(Environment.CommandLine, "(?:""[^""]*""|[^ ]+)") _
  .Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).Skip(1).ToArray()
```

Note: This parsing doesn't handle escape sequences as the original method, so you can't use for example `""` or `\"` inside a quoted parameter to put a quotation mark in it. If you want to use the original method, you need to follow it's escaping rules and the arguments would have to be written as:

```
d:\littleProgram.exe "d:\test 2\folder\\" test.pdf
```